# IPython sympy math pretty print doesn't work

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy

I am trying to print a scipy result with pretty print but it seems output not in latex format.

```
import sympy
from sympy import *

init_printing() 

var('x,y')
y = sympy.expand((x+y)**2)
y
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to mathjax cdn? Does Math in Markdown cells work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of SymPy (0.7.6.1). There was an issue with printing which was fixed in the 0.7.6.1 bugfix release.

Comment: You are right, 0.7.6.1 has fixed this issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need set pretty printing up:

```
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()
```

Now it should work.

Also install matplotlib.

Comment: You need to have matplotlib installed.

Comment: yes, I have installed  Anaconda package for everything should be there already!